# Adding a JOIN to query resulting in a fail

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to add my users table to my existing query so that I can match the users.id with the forum_topics.topic_creator, so I can match those and enable myself to assign that with that users username.

This is my original query.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) 
   AS tid2 FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_posts 
   AS p on t.id = p.topic_id WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid." 
   GROUP BY t.id DESC")
```

I then tried doing this..

```
$query2 =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) 
   AS tid2 FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_posts 
   AS p on t.id = p.topic_id WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid." 
   INNER JOIN users AS u
   ON t.topic_creator = u.id
   GROUP BY t.id DESC")
or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
```

I am getting the fail message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` clause should come **after** join:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 
FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN 
     forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id INNER JOIN 
     users AS u ON t.topic_creator = u.id
WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid."
GROUP BY t.id DESC
```

**EDIT:**

To select the `username` as well:

```
SELECT t.*,u.username, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 
FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN 
     forum_posts AS p on t.id = p.topic_id INNER JOIN 
     users AS u ON t.topic_creator = u.id
WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid."
GROUP BY t.id DESC
```

Comment: Ok, this isn't giving me any errors, but my username isn't outputting. I am assigning the username column field to it like this..`$creator = $row2['username'];`

Comment: After further review, this is throwing off the purpose of the original query. I have this associated with a link as well. When I click on the link nothing shows up

Comment: @Becky: Do you have the username field in the table `forum_topics`? (that is the only table used in select clause) I guess, it is in the table `users`. And you haven't tried to select it from table `users`.

Comment: No, I don't have the username field in the `forum_topics` table. I have topic_creator which is an integer that matches the `users` id.

Comment: @Becky: Then select the username from users table. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: ok the username now works, but my original query is still breaking for my links. The links part comes from the `$cid`.

Comment: @Becky: The link is in php code, right? So, it doesn't have anything to do with the query.

Comment: It does though. I am getting the cid, which is the category id affiliated with the post that was made. That enables me to click on the link and see the thread I am trying to see. `<td><a href='forum_view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'><?php echo $title; ?></a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87082/discussion-between-becky-and-raging-bull).

Comment: Didn't mean to do that... This was my original query before I tried to modify and get the username... `$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id` ='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC")`

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause has to be placed after the `INNER JOIN`.

```
$query2 =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) 
AS tid2 FROM forum_topics AS t 
JOIN forum_posts AS p ON t.id = p.topic_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.topic_creator = u.id
WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid." 
GROUP BY t.id DESC")
or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(p.topic_id) AS tid2 
FROM forum_topics t 
JOIN forum_posts p ON (t.id = p.topic_id )
INNER JOIN users u ON (t.topic_creator = u.id)
 WHERE t.category_id = ".$cid."
GROUP BY t.id DESC`
```